# C++ Linked List – a new pointer that is not used to traverse the list CAN print the list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I created a simple dynamic linked list implementation in C++ which has a head node of 42, and after which, prompts the user if he/she wants additional numbers to add to the list.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int x;
    Node *next;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char choice;

    Node *start = new Node;

    start->next = NULL;
    start->x = 42;

    Node *traverser = start;

    while (1) {
        cout << "Add item to the list (Y/N)? ";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 'Y') {
            traverser->next = new Node;
            traverser = traverser->next;
            traverser->next = NULL;
            cout << "New item: ";
            cin >> traverser->x;
        }
        else {

            cout << "Linked List:\n";
            Node *p;
            for (p = start; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
                cout << p->x << endl;                    //QUESTION HERE!
            }
            cout << "\nProgram dismissed.";
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the question, as indicated in the code block, lies on the pointer *p. The head of my linked list is named start, while the pointer that traverses and adds items to the list is named traverser. Why the heck is *p able to print all that's in the list when it is only assigned to the head

```
p = start
```

and not to the body of the list. I would've understood that this works for printing

```
cout << "Linked List:\n";
for (traverser = start; traverser != NULL; traverser = traverser->next) {
    cout << traverser->x << endl;
}
```

But *p being able to print the whole list confused me, a lot!

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "not to the body of the list"?

Comment: `p` points to the same thing `start` does.  So whatever you can do with `start` you can do with `p`.

Comment: Pointers "point" to things, and they can change to point to other things through assignment. `p` starts at `start`, then is changed to point to the next `Node`, etc. until the next `Node` is `NULL`.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe by not to the body of the list, I meant that the pointer is initialized as *p = start, and not *p = traverser. We know that start only contains one item – 42, the head of the list. While traverser contains the whole body of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*p is able to print the whole list, because *p (initially) points to the start of the list. After the start of the list, comes the body of the list, that you linked with

```
if (choice == 'Y') {
        traverser->next = new Node;
        traverser = traverser->next;
        traverser->next = NULL;
        cout << "New item: ";
        cin >> traverser->x;
    }
```

Understand here, that initially traverser and start both manipulate the same object. To put it in layman's terms, when you're using pointers, you're not cloning values, you're cloning instructions on how to access the values. Perhaps this was the source of your confusion?

So, the `Node* start` points to a node. `Node* traverse` points to the same node, as you declared `Node *traverser = start;` You could manipulate the value of the node in question via traverse->x or start->x, and get the exact same result.

Comment: Thanks! But one question, you mentioned "initially traverser and start both manipulate the same object", which object exactly are we talking about here? An object is supposed to be, say Node obj right? If I put a pointer upfront, i.e. Node *obj, then it's not technically an object anymore?

Comment: By object, I meant the Node which the pointers start and traverse point to. The one created with `new Node;`. Of course, seen how it can only be accessed via the pointers that point to it, it's existence can easily go unnoticed. So in short, Node *p is a pointer, not an object, but it points to an object.

Comment: Wow, great answer! That completely eradicates my confusion now. So new node is the object! All this time I've been trying to find where exactly the object is, when in fact, it's created by 'new' all along. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

p is just a pointer variable, like any other variable it can have different values , but it points to addresses.

```
p = start
```

p starts pointing toward your first node.

```
 p = p->next
```

it starts pointing towards next node.
Where are you confused ?

Comment: You see, in the beginning, I initialized the head node start->x = 42. Which means the struct object start only has one item – the head of the list. Then I initialized a DIFFERENT struct object *traverse = start, which means that it points to start. In the body of the program, I added items to the list by dynamically changing the *traverser pointer, not *start. Hence, initalizing a new Node *p = start, should only contain 42, not the whole list, because start and traverser are two different struct object pointers.

Comment: `start` and `traverse` *point* to the same thing at the beginning. You need to understand the difference between different objects in memory and how  more than one pointer can point to them.

Comment: @Loqz : You did not create a *DIFFERENT* struct object! You created a different **pointer** to the struct object, the first node of the linked list remains the same, which you created at the beginning `Node *start = new Node;`, you just created different pointers which point to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`traverser` does not contain the body of the list. `start`does.

Let's review the contents of your program:

```
    Node *start = new Node;
```

`start` will always point to the node created here. `start` is always the beginning of the list.

From this node you can travel through the **entire** list using the nodes `next` member.

```
Node *traverser = start;
```

`traverser` is initially the same node as the `start` node. `traverser` indicates the **end** of the list.  You can't use `traverser` to travel through the list.  The reason `traverser` is used is that it simplifies the insertion of a new node at the end of the list.

The last statement is shown by the statements

```
traverser->next = new Node;
traverser = traverser->next;
traverser->next = 0;
```

The last statement tells us that we can't follow the `traverser` node anywhere. This is the end of the list.

So `start`is the entire list, `start->x` is the first value in the list. `start->next` is a pointer to the next element in the list.

Now, we don't want to corrupt the `start`of the list. So let's make a copy of the pointer to the first element, and call that copy p. Use p to look through the list. `p` is only useful for this small section of the code, whereas `start` and `traverser` is useful for the entire program.

```
Node* p = start;  
for (; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
     cout << p->x << endl;
 }
```

The last element printed will be the same element as `traverser`points to.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I might've misunderstood the unique functionality of struct object pointer. I thought that declaring two struct objects, i.e. Node *start and Node *traverser, would be two entirely different objects independent of each other, which caused the confusion. I now realize that struct objects and struct pointers are completely different.